# Gradle print directories in a folder - X level

Tags: gradle, structure, directory, depth

I have the following folder structure under build folder (which you get during a Gradle build):

```
CDROM/disk1
CDROM/disk1/disk1file1a.txt
CDROM/disk1/disk1file1b.txt

CDROM/disk2/disk2file2a.txt
CDROM/disk2/disk2file2btxt
CDROM/disk2/disk2folder2x
CDROM/disk2/disk2folder2y

CDROM/disk3
CDROM/disk3/disk3
CDROM/disk3/disk33
CDROM/disk3/disk33/disk3


CDROM/folder1

CDROM/file1.txt
```

How can I tell Gradle to show me the following:

1. Print only the top level / direct child folders (only) in folder "CDROM" 
   i.e. it should print only disk1, disk2, disk3 and folder1
2. Print only the top level / direct child folders (only) which has a pattern of disk[0-9] i.e. diskX where X is a number.
   i.e. it should print only disk1, disk2 and disk3

The following will do it, but I think there should be an efficient way to achieve the same and where one can define patterns and DON'T have to use "IF" statements that I have used below.

```
FileTree dirs = fileTree (dir: "$buildDir/CDROM", include: "disk*/**")

        dirs.visit { FileVisitDetails fd ->

                if (fd.directory && fd.name.startsWith('disk')){

                        println "------  $buildDir/CDROM_Installers/${fd.name}   ---------------"

                }

        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By top level if you mean only direct children of `CDROM` then this should be as easy as:

```
new File("${buildDir}/CDROM").eachDir{ if(it.name ==~/disk.*/) println it}
```

If you want more control on depth and other things, then you can try variations of following code:

```
new File("${buildDir}/CDROM").traverse( [maxDepth: 2, filter: ~/.*disk\d/, 
                                        type: groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES]){
   println it // or do whatever
}
```

see [traverse](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) for more details.